# change message in payment section when using paypal

Tags: paypal-standard

Is there a way to add messaging into a paypal checkout? 
Many customers abandon their basket at payment because they think they require a paypal account. The option to pay by card is available only at the end of the checkout which is confusing for some.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using Paypal Express checkout? Can you post screenshots to what your checkout looks like? If you seriously have customers abandoning because they are going into PayPal Express, the simplest answer is to pay the $30 a month fee for Payments Pro (or another credit card processor).

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to overload a block class.

Are you referring to the "You will be redirected to the PayPal website when you place an order." message in Payment Options?

A quick look reveals a few different versions according to your checkout settings, I've listed the 3 I see in the standard Mage setup below, and the class you will need to overload...

***(Express Checkout)***
Message : You will be redirected to the PayPal website. 
Path to file : /app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Block/Express/Form.php 
Class to extend : Mage_Paypal_Block_Express_Form 
Method to overload : _construct()

***(Standard Checkout)***
Message : You will be redirected to the PayPal website **when you place an order.** 
Path to file : /app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Block/Standard/Form.php 
Class to extend : Mage_Paypal_Block_Standard_Form 
Method to overload : _construct()

***(Redirect Checkout)***
Message : You will be redirected to the PayPal website **in a few seconds.** 
Path to file : /app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Block/Standard/Redirect.php 
Class to extend : Mage_Paypal_Block_Standard_Redirect 
Method to overload : _toHtml()

Roll yourself a module, extend the class you need to (from above) and modify the method listed above to use the text/markup you want.

Sorry I don't have an example to hand, try to role your own and mark the answer if you succeed, comment if you need some more help but first make sure you're 100% on [Overriding Magento Blocks, Models, Helpers and Controllers](http://inchoo.net/magento/overriding-magento-blocks-models-helpers-and-controllers/)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

With regards to cygnus' response - Great Answer and worked with me. For the inexperienced this maybe looked a little daunting at first but just ensure you leave the old version in place and rename as Form_old.php so if you get it wrong you can revert back to it by deleting your updated file and rename the original file back to Form.php. Simply put download the file open it up and then edit the message ensuring you don't delete or change any of the code outside the brackets and then you can put what you like, it scrolls well so you are not limited to the length of message.

Comment: ThanksRobert, and also cheers for recommending the roll back, I forgot about this.